# Problema na consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, query

estou com um problema ao fazer uma consulta mysql.
Eu quero selecionar o id e o nome de todos os presentes, exceto os que já estão na tabela de reservas.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT
    tb_presentes.id_presente AS value_id,
    tb_presentes.nome AS label
FROM
    tb_presentes
INNER JOIN
    tb_reserva
ON
    tb_presentes.id_presente <> tb_reserva.id_presente
WHERE
    tb_presentes.id_cat_presente = 2
ORDER BY
    value_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize [*NOT IN*](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php) para pesquisar valores que não estejam listados nos parametros

```
NOT IN (valor1, Valor2...Valores)
```

E preencha esta lista com os dados da sua tabela de Reservas ("onde ID NOT IN Reserva").

Ficaria da seguinte forma

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tb_presentes.id_presente AS value_id,
    tb_presentes.nome AS label
FROM
    tb_presentes
WHERE
    tb_presentes.id_presente NOT IN (select tb_reserva.id_presente from tb_reserva)
AND
    tb_presentes.id_cat_presente = 2
ORDER BY
    value_id
```

Comment: Cara... valeu mano. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!!!